# Get Value for Specific Select Option in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to get the value for a select option in my django template.  I can iterate through an object like this:

```
<select id="id_name" name="name">
  {% for x, y in form.fields.name.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}">{{ y }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

but is there any way to get a specific value eg; form.fields.name.choices.2? without looping?  Thanks!

Comment: `form.fields.name.choices.2.0` for the "key" and `form.fields.name.choices.2.1` for the "value".

Comment: Unfortunately {{ form.fields.name.choices.2.0 }} or {{ form.fields.name.choices.2.1 }} doesn't seem to be giving me the key or the value.  When I put in {{ form.fields.name.choices }} I get this: 
<django.forms.models.ModelChoiceIterator object at 0x7fd10c029880> but I don't know what to do with it besides looping.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
form.fields.name.choices.queryset.values.2
```

to get third element in a dict with your choices. Or you use

```
form.fields.name.choices.queryset.values_list.2
```

to get the choice as tuple.
See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list